# AlertController como respuesta a un URLSession

Tags: ios, swift3

Intento modificar los datos de usuario de una app a traves de la conexión con un servidor web el cual responde a dicha petición con un boolean. El código implementado para la conexión esta bien pues al comprobar los datos, se reflejan correctamente a los ingresados en la app. El problema es que al verificar la respuesta del servidor intento mostrar un mensaje pero siempre me da un error.
Por favor ayuda

Este es el código para el requerimiento al servicio web

```
func Modificar(usuario:Usuario, completion: ((Bool) -> (Void))?){
    var respuesta: Bool = false
    if isConnectedToNetwork(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(DOMINIO)\(MODIFICARUSUARIO)") else { return }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  // the request is JSON

        let jsonObject: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        jsonObject.setValue("\(usuario.apellido)", forKey: "APELLIDOUSUARIO")
        jsonObject.setValue("\(usuario.ceduldaRuc)", forKey: "CEDULARUC")
        jsonObject.setValue("\(usuario.celular)", forKey: "CELULARUSUARIO")
        jsonObject.setValue("\(usuario.clave)", forKey: "CLAVEUSUARIO")
        jsonObject.setValue("1", forKey: "CODIGOPRIVILEGIO")
        jsonObject.setValue("\(usuario.id)", forKey: "CODIGOUSUARIO")
        jsonObject.setValue("\(usuario.correo)", forKey: "CORREOUSUARIO")
        jsonObject.setValue("ACTIVO", forKey: "ESTADO")
        jsonObject.setValue("/Date(1502920131070-0700)/", forKey: "FECHAACTUALIZACION")
        jsonObject.setValue("/Date(1502920131070-0700)/", forKey: "FECHAREGISTRO")
        jsonObject.setValue("\(usuario.nombre)", forKey: "NOMBREUSUARIO")

        var jsonResult: Data!
        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: []) as Data
        }catch{
            print("Error result")
        }
        request.httpBody = jsonResult

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
            do
            {
                respuesta = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.allowFragments, .mutableContainers]) as! Bool
                if respuesta
                {
                    completion?(true)

                }
                else
                {
                    completion?(false)

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

y así es como lo uso al dar clic en un botón de la interface

```
UsuarioExterno().Modificar(usuario: usuarioActual){ result in
if result
{
    Preferencia().modificar(parametro: "USUARIOSINCRONIZADO", valor:true)
}
else
{
    Preferencia().modificar(parametro: "USUARIOSINCRONIZADO", valor:true)
}
let alert = UIAlertController()
alert.title = "Mi app"
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default,handler: nil))
alert.message =  self.usuarioActual.Modificar() ? "Todo bien" : "Todo mal"//copia en base local
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

self.LimpiarCampos()
self.MostrarDatos(usuario: Usuario().buscar(incluirInactivo: false).firstObject as! Usuario)
}
```

Finalmente este es el error que obtengo por el UIALERTCONTROLLER

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu `URLSession.dataTask` te está devolviendo una closure en segundo plano. Como estás intentando mostrar una alerta desde segundo plano, ésta no se te muestra.

Prueba lo siguiente, en tu función **Modificar**:

```
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
        do
        {
            respuesta = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.allowFragments, .mutableContainers]) as! Bool
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?(respuesta != nil)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 completion?(false)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```